# Can app scripts MailApp.sendMail send emails with '+' in them?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am using MailApp.sendEmail function to send emails from a google sheet.  While testing I made use of gmail's feature that allows you to create "new" email addresses from your own using the plus sign to generate lots of different test email addresses.

i.e. if my address is joe.bloggs@gmail.com I can also use joe.blogs+anythinghere@gmail.com

Strangley, when I send my test emails using MailApp.sendEmail using one of these email addresses it never arrives, but if I send it to my own base address it does.

Is this an "undocumented" feature or am I missing something that allows it to work?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

It does arrive it's just GMail doesn't put it into the Inbox as you are sending it to yourself from a script, you should see it in the Sent Mail folder.

Comment: I am sending these test emails to myself but when I use the base email address (i.e. joe.bloggs@gmail.com) the email does appear in my in box and when I use the extended address (i.e.joe.bloggs+test@gmail.com) it does not.  The emails to both addresses also appear in the sent mail.

I email stuff to my gmail account all the time using the web interface, including using addresses expanded with '+' , and I always receive them in the my inbox.

Comment: I see the same thing and I'd just assumed this was an undocumented feature. I'd be interested to hear if you manage to get these coming into your inbox.

Comment: Several days later and non delivery messages from gmail about the mails, but they still haven't arrived.  Still floating in the ether of the internet.